# NuGet Compatible vs Computed Framework (Xamarin and .NET 6)

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, nuget

We are currently looking at migrating existing Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS applications to .NET 6 (we aren't at this stage going to use MAUI).

A big part of this process is understanding which NuGet packages we need to update or replace.

We're just trying to understand the difference between a package being compatible with a framework, and a framework being an additionally computed framework.

We can see for some of the packages we are using that net6.0-ios and net6.0-android are additionally computed frameworks rather than being compatible. What does this mean in terms of whether or not a net6.0-ios or net6.0-android app could consume the package?

Comment: I talked to David Ortinau, Principal Product Manager at Microsoft, at the Techorama conference in Antwerp a few weeks ago and he said that the computed frameworks should not be relied on when migrating the package references of a Xamarin.Forms project. Computed frameworks ***may*** work, but they are not actually targeted by the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends.

Lets say you are trying to consume a package that only targets netstandard1.0 or above. That package will be totally fine to consume.

However, if you are attempting to consume a package that has multiple targets, lets say

- netstandard1.0
- Xamarin.iOS
- monoandroid13.0

That package will only partially work. The netstandard stuff will definitely work. monoandroid13.0 will most likely work. However, since there are breaking changes between Xamarin.iOS and net6.0-ios then that part won't work.

Most preferably, for packages that target a specific platform, that should at least be net6.0-android or net6.0-ios, otherwise you will encounter issues.

Comment: I think our confusion comes from the fact that net6.0-ios is supposed to be backwards compatible with Xamarin.iOS. I'm assuming that means a net6.0-ios app can use a Xamarin.iOS package but not the other way round?

Comment: No it cannot. There are breaking changes in the API so you cannot consume Xamarin.iOS packages from net6.0-ios or vice-versa

Comment: Good point, but then the package shouldn't show `.net6-android` as a "computed framework", right? Personally, I would just try it, if it does list that.